# Superquadric equation: Breaking down

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spheres

According to this [textbook](https://cse.buffalo.edu/%7Ejryde/cse673/files/superquadrics.pdf), the following superquadric equation describes the 3D surface of a unit sphere:

$$
S(\theta, \phi) = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) \cos(\phi); \\
\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi); \\
\sin(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

S(,) comes from the spherical product between two 2D surfaces h() and m():

$$
m(\theta) = [\cos(\theta); \sin(\theta)], \quad -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

$$
h(\phi) = [\cos(\phi); \sin(\phi)], \quad -\pi \leq \phi \leq \pi
$$

The textbook doesn't fully explain the detailed breakdown of $S(,)$. I would like to know how all the terms in $S(,)$ are found, specially if there is an actual "spherical product" formula.

Comment: "superquadric equation" sounds sensational , but it only means that three (instead of two) terms "magically" add up to $1$.